# Can WiFi repeaters cause interference?

Tags: internet, wifi-configuration, network-interface, interference

I have a old Linksys router the I converted into a repeater using dd-wrt firmware. Its been running great but I'm just curious is it possible that it could be interfering with the main router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Then you must know how exactly your repeater work**

I will make it simple as I can
A WiFi Repeater effectively contains two wireless routers, similar to the wireless router you already have in your home or office. One of these wireless routers picks up the existing WiFi network then transfers the signal to the other wireless router, which transmits the boosted signal.

What ddwrt do is: to separate the router to two parts that's the smart repeater "bridge"
The old one only take the signal then boost it without make any change or use any layers.

Your repeater simply connect on the same channel and baud of your main router, normally that will make interfering, if the data was different 
"two wireless signals with different data" "heart-beat"
but in your case both signals have the same data and "heart-beat", so there is no interfering between them.

But there is other problem here, repeater will slow down your internet bandwidth "speed" that's because when you flash it with ddwrt this firmware will separate the router and the antenna to two parts and that's mean if your main router have 2mb speed your repeater will have 1mb , some Cisco repeater will have 1.5 don't ask me how its "CISCO" others will boost the bandwidth without losing any speed simply because they made it for this propose with two signals at the same time and two separate CPU and NVRAM the old one only boost the signal that's all

**But what about your main router?**
you will not notice any change of the speed on that router, **BUT** with heavy use "streaming videos or sharing big files" will put your router into a loop and made the CPU usage high then freeze you will notice that only on heavy use with different users but **NOT** all routers will have this issues only cheap one

Comment: Excellent explanation, thank you, to clarify one thing thought, the bandwidth issue exists within the repeater not the host router correct?

Comment: just saw your edit, disregard my previous comment